# My action bar has a shadow which is unexpected

Tags: android

On my action bar, I noticed a certain shaded edge edging in between the appbar and status bar. 
Any idea on how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: put app:elevation="0dp" in appbarlayout

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine.